# how to modify detailsview in asp.net with bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, detailsview

I have an asp.net project and I want to change its style using bootstap. I couldn't change stle of complex components such as detailsview. Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had this problem before and decided to use FormsView instead. If possible, I'll suggest you to use FormsView as well. DetailsView provides minimum customization level and you won't be able to get rid of the table. This tutorial might help you : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288035.aspx